# Acessar uma propriedate de um array de objetos dentro de outro array de objetos

Tags: javascript, map

Enquanto estava usando map, filter, reduce para acessar dados de um array de objetos estava tudo calmo, agora me deparei em acessar um aninhamento entao travou tudo aqui.

const objetos = [{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: [
    { cc: 1, dd: 2, ee: 3' },
    { cc: 4, dd: 5, ee: 6' }
  ]

pensei em acessar com map (objetos.map(c => c.c.dd) para receber como resultado: 2 e 5
usando filter e spread eu consigo MAS, nao quero filtrar, quero apenas receber o valor contido em dd

EDITANDO  ...user140828

const posts = [{
  titulo: 'titulo a',
  assunto: 'assunto a',
  votos: [
    { leitor: 1, nota: 4}, (de um total máximo de 5 pontos)
    { leitor: 4, nota: 5 },
    { leitor: 2, nota: 3 }
  ]
]}

Do que preciso de cada Post do array de Posts:
o component do vue precisa pontuar de 1 a 5 um post qd o usuário quiser votar no post.
o component do vue mostra a pontuação atual do post ao leitor e permite que ele tbm pontue se for de sua vontade.
preciso do total de votos: 3 votos.
preciso da média de votos (para alimentar o component vue) nota 4 + 5 + 3 = 12 que divido pelo número de votos (3) chego ao resultado 4 e com esse resultado alimento o componente então o usuário quando lê o post ele saberá que aquele post ja foi votado 3 vezes e a pontuação atual é de 4 pontos de um total de 5 portanto o post tá em alta entendeu?

com o seu codigo consegui tudo isso mas, na hora que preciso pegar a média (soma dos votos / total de votos) é que acho sujei o código.
 o map não é para obter o length e sim os registros das notas que esta em um objeto votos do objeto post.
no reduce, estou somando todas as notas e o resultado do reduce estou dividindo com o total de notas para obter a média de pontos(votos).

com o seu codigo já resolvi tudo e esta funcionando só acho que sujei o código e queria um avaliador para corrigir (ou não).

seu código:
const dd = objetos.map(objeto => objeto.c.map(c => c.dd))

peguei ele e com forIn matei o primeiro map pois o componente roda sob forIn entao ficou assim:

post.votos.map(c => c.nota)
com isso, tenho todos os votos(notas 4, 5, 3) então usei
.reduce(.....) para somar os votos 4+5+3=12

agora que acho que fiz porqueira:
pra pegar o total de registro de votos (no exemplo acima são 3 registros) usei:

post.votos.map(c => c.nota).length) = 3, então peguei a média dessa forma:

post.votos.map(c => c.nota).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / post.votos.map(c => c.nota).length)

Como disse, com seu código eu resolvi tudo mas acho que pequei no final e quaria sua opiniao já que foi através do seu código que consegui acessar a propriedade votos  que é um array de dentro de outro array.

Expliquei direito agora ou confundi mais ainda?

Desculpe por seu tempo, como eu disse, graças a você esta tudo funcionando, mas acredito que chamar outro map apenas para pegar o total de registros de nota ficou meio estranho.
Independente de qualquer coisa fico muito agradecida por ter me oriantada a usar map dentro de map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem um array dentro de um array, logo para isolar essas propriedades, irá precisar de um `map` dentro de um map.

```js
const objetos = [{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: [ { cc: 1, dd: 2, ee: 3 }, { cc: 4, dd: 5, ee: 6 } ] }]

const dd = objetos.map(objeto => objeto.c.map(c => c.dd))
//dd contém uma matriz, com as propriedades dd de todos os objetos
console.log(dd)
//como no exemplo só existe um objeto na raiz, você pode acessa-lo diretamente no índice 0
console.log(dd[0])
```

Para encontrar as médias dos votos por outro lado, você não precisa necessariamente usar o método map, você pode chamar diretamente o `reduce` e passar não apenas o `callback`, mas também o valor inicial para o acumulador (nesse caso, 0).

```js
const posts = [{ titulo: 'titulo a', assunto: 'assunto a', votos: [{ leitor: 1, nota: 4 }, { leitor: 4, nota: 5 }, { leitor: 2, nota: 3 }] }]

//Encontrando notas, e então as médias
const notas = posts.map(post => post.votos.map(voto => voto.nota))
const medias1 = notas.map(nota => nota.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / nota.length)

//Encontrando médias diretamente
const medias2 = posts.map(post => post.votos.reduce((acc, voto) => acc + voto.nota, 0) / post.votos.length)

console.log(medias1)
console.log(medias2)
```

Comment: Caiu como luva. Grato por sua ajuda, foi de imensa importância!

Comment: Com base no seu snippet eu consegui isso atraves de um for in: queria saber se estou aporcalhando esse código dividindo  o resultado da soma pelo valor total de registros? meti as maos pelas pernas? ou com o proprio reduce eu poderia saber quantas iterações ocoreram e dai dividir?
posts.map(p => p.votos.map(c => c.int_votos)) com seu codigo
 já com for in: post.votos.map(c => c.int_votos).reduce((a, b) => a + b / post.votos.map(c => c.int_votos).length - 1)
funciona bem mas acho que matei o javascript não?

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que você está tentando fazer. Encontrar a média? Porque o que você está fazendo é dividir o resultado de cada iteração do `reduce` pelo tamanho do seu array, não o valor retornado do reduce como deveria ser. Invocar `map` num array apenas para encontrar o `length` também não faz sentido nenhum, o retorno do map sempre tem o mesmo tamanho que o array, pra que invocar map?

Comment: vou explicar em outra pergunta pq por aqui não tem espaço.

Comment: Menino tu és um gênio!!!! eu sabia que aquele map tava estranho apesar de funcionar a gosto eu estava incomodada. Até hoje eu não havia entendido o acumulador do reduce e sem quere, com teu exemplo acabei sem querer entendendo o propósito do acc. Tua sintaxe é curta, pura e eficaz..voilá.....encaixou direitinho. Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode extrair as propriedades combinando array.from e destructing.
**Por exemplo:**

```
const users = [
  { name: 'John' , 
    active: false }, 
  { name: 'Mary' , 
    active: true }, 
];

const userNames = Array.from(users, ({ name }) => name);
```

Comment: Show!!!! é o es rompendo o "quase impossível" e vcs mestres nos mostrando o caminho